# How can I trigger checkbox selections from dropdown menu without using JavaScript?

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, drop-down-menu

In my asp.net page, I have several checkboxes and 1 drop down.  I want certain checkboxes to be selected depending on the dropdown selection.

I know how to do this using javascript but I would like to do so using codebehind c#.  Any help?

Comment: "I know how to do this using javascript but I would like to do so using codebehind c#" - specific reason for this? If yes, logic would remain same be it JS or C#. You have make dropdown `autopostback` to server and write conditional logic in it's event handler. Please show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by setting `AutoPostBack` of dropdown to `true` and within Page_Load, make a check like

```
If(IsPostBack)
//Get the selected Item of your dropDown i.e. dropDown1.SelectedItem.Text
// and populate the comboBoxes based on your dropDown's selected value
```

If you want anything else, let me know.

Hope it helps!